# how to replace a string in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a question about using replaceAll() function.

if a string has parentheses as a pair, replace it with "",

```
while(S.contains("()"))
        {
            S = S.replaceAll("\\(\\)", "");
        }
```

but why in `replaceAll("\\(\\)", "");`need to use `\\(\\)`?

Answer (score 2):

Because as noted by the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), the argument is a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Parenthesis in a regular expression are used for grouping. If you're going to match parenthesis as part of a regular expression they must be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `replaceAll` expects a regex and `(` and `)` have a special meaning in a regex expressions and need to be escaped.

An alternative is to use `replace`, which counter-intuitively does the same thing as `replaceAll` but takes a string as an input instead of a regex:

```
S = S.replace("()", "");
```

Comment: @xagyg WRONG! You seem to forget that `String` implements `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 1):

First, your code can be replaced with:

```
S = S.replace("()", "");
```

without the `while` loop.

Second, the first argument to `.replaceAll()` is a regular expression, and parens are special tokens in regular expressions (they are grouping operators).

And also, `.replaceAll()` replaces *all* occurrences, so you didn't even need the `while` loop here. Starting with Java 6 you could also have written:

```
S = S.replaceAll("\\Q()\\E", "");
```

It is let as an exercise to the reader as to what `\Q` and `\E` are: http://regularexpressions.info gives the answer ;)

Comment: Erm, wrong: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29 -- this method has two overloads

Answer (score 1):

S = S.replaceAll("\(\)", "") = the argument is a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Because the method's first argument is a regex expression, and `()` are special characters in regex, so you need to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

Because parentheses are special characters in regexps, so you need to escape them.  To get a literal `\` in a string in Java you need to escape it like so : `\\`.

So `()` => `\(\)` => `\\(\\)`

Comment: but why need to escape twice?

Comment: @ratzip Normally regex needs one \ to escape special meaning of meta-character, but in String \ is also special character (you use it to escape special meaning of some characters like quotes \", or to make special characters like new line \n). So to pass \ char to regex engine you first need to escape its special meaning in String with another \ before it.